# Empty string gets passed from one Form to another in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, textbox

I have following problem:
I have a `Form1` where I open a second `Form2` from it. Now I have a save `Button` in `Form2` where entries from Textboxes are saved to a csv file. But I want to save some entries from `Form1` too. The `Textbox` entries from `Form2` are getting saved but entries from `Form1` are empty strings. Following code:

In Form1:

```
public void showInputToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
        form2.Show();
    }
```

to open the second Form via the first one and functions to grab the entries from the Form1 Textboxes:

```
    public String getLocation()
    {
        return LocationBox.Text;
    }

    public String getFilesLoc()
    {
        return FilesLocation.Text;
    }
```

In Form2 I have the following:

```
    private Form1 m_form = null;

    public Form2(Form1 f)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_form = f;
    }
```

and then the function to grab the entries and save them:

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        proc.setParams(form1.getLocation(),getFilesLoc());
        proc.saveCurrentSettings();
    }
```

I left the other parameters out. So entries from `Form2` are read correctly but the ones from `Form1` are just an empty string (""). What can I do?

Comment: You are creating a new form1 just before you call for the values and you don't show it so nothing is initalised in the gui

Comment: So how would it be correct? When I create it after the values then it won't find them.

Comment: @ZoomVirus, It is the answer not the comment.

Comment: What you expect to have in `FilesLocation.Text` immediately after `Form1 form1 = new Form1()`? It is normal to be empty string. Is there `form1.ShowDialog()` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the click handler, you're creating a *new* `Form1` here:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

That will have empty values - but you want the value from the *existing* form which you kept a reference to in your constructor - so use it!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    proc.setParams(m_form.getLocation(), m_form.getFilesLoc());
    proc.saveCurrentSettings();
}
```

(I'd strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions, quite possibly turning those `get` methods into properties, and also considering passing the *values* into your `Form2` constructor instead of the `Form1` reference itself. It depends on whether you need to "see" any changes made to `Form1` after the construction of `Form2`.)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 proc.setParams(m_form.getLocation(), m_form.getFilesLoc());
 proc.saveCurrentSettings();
```

you are not using the reference of `Form1` but creating a new object and using that.